# How to import a dataset from Dropbox?

Tags: r, dropbox

I have an iPad Pro as my primary computer, and am running R Studio from a cloud server for a class.  I am trying to figure out how to import data sets, since my local working directory is on the server.  I have been trying to download the package repmis, since I have been reading that that package allows for data set import from Dropbox.  However, when I try to download the package, I get "Error:configuration failed for openssl" and a similar one for curl.  I tried to install openssl but instead it says I need to install "deb" for ubuntu operating systems, but I can't find that in R Studio in the package database.  (And I can't install curl without openssl either) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

If it's a relatively straightforward data set like a CSV, XML, JSON or even an .RData file you can use a Dropbox sharing URL to read it. Here's an example (it's a live URL) for reading in a CSV directly from a shared Dropbox link:

```
read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xg5u0z1gtjcuol/mtcars.csv?dl=1")
```

The `dl=1` won't be the default from a "share this link" copy (it'll probably be `dl=0`.

Comment: That seemed like it would work, but then I got an error code reading error in file (file, "rt") : cannot open the connection. I am using a .csv that should be readable and i changed it to dl=1 and that didn't work either.

Comment: If you're on windows try `readr::read_csv()` instead of `read.csv()`

Comment: Changing dl=0 to dl=1 was important for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
urla<- 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/fakecode/xyz.txt?raw=1' 
bpdata<-read.table(urla, header=TRUE)


scode<-'https://www.dropbox.com/s/lp6fleehcsb3wi9/protoBP.R?raw=1'
source(scode)

readAndPlotZoomForYear(urla, 2019)
```

Basically I wanted to source code from a file in Dropbox and to use the read.table() function on a tab delineated data file. I found this could be done by replacing the string after the question mark with raw=1 in the Dropbox file links.

Comment: Being new I am not sure why all my comments were stripped out. Sorry about that. Basically I wanted to source code from a file in Dropbox and to use the read.table() function on a tab delineated data file. I found this could be done by replacing the string after the question mark with raw=1 in the Dropbox file links.